# Deploying a Vite Vuejs app to Apache server

Tags: vue.js, apache, xampp, vuejs3, vite

I am using xampp apache server on a local machine.

I tried `npm run preview` and `serve -s dist`. It can be access but u have to put a port after the project name `localhost:3000` something like this.

I also tried copying the dist folder to another folder in xampps htdocs (system_name) `system_name/dist`.
I want to access like `localhost/system_name`. When I tried to access it, it produces white screen. I already configured `.htaccess` and double checked src and href pointing at js and css files.

My htaccess file also looks like this.

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.html$1
```

This is the actual document root path (where the dist files are copied, index.html, assets and .htaccess)

```
C:/xampp/htdocs/production/
```

This is also the contents of the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/production/assets/denr-cdf828ad.png">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>NGPDBS</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/production/assets/index-c66d07a1.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/production/assets/index-5f93e947.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

My vite.config.js file looks like this

```
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'node:url'

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
  ],
  base: '/production/',
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  },
})
```

When I access it on my browser (`localhost/production`) it gives me white screen but the icon logo can be seen besides the Title. There are also no errors in the console.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Typically you simply copy the build output (`dist` folder) into your Apache document root. If you're using client-side routing, you'll also want a `RewriteRule` to handle direct URLs. You haven't included enough detail to provide any more specific answers though

Comment: Thats what I actually did, I copied a folder and created a .htaccess file. I updated my post also. thanks @Phil

Comment: If you right-click on that white screen page and select _"view source"_, does it look the same as the `index.html` contents?

Comment: @Phil yes, its exactly the same content as ```index.html```

Comment: Do the other build files exist at the correct locations and have the right content? Eg, check `C:/xampp/htdocs/production/assets/index-c66d07a1.js`. It should exist and contain some minified JS code

Comment: @Phil yes, I can access ```http://localhost/production/assets/index-c66d07a1.js``` in the url and returns the code

Comment: So which URL are you using to open your app in the browser? It should be `http://localhost/production/` and definitely not anything starting with `file:///`

Comment: @Phil this one ```http://localhost/production/``` yeah, I edited my previous comment

Comment: ... though this last line in your `.htaccess` is odd _`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index.html$1`_. I don't think that should be there

Comment: @Phil ok. i removed it on my .htaccess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're intending to serve your application under a sub-directory like `system_name`, you'll need to configure Vite to build your app using a [Public Base Path](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#public-base-path)

> If you are deploying your project under a nested public path, simply specify the [base config option](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#base) and all asset paths will be rewritten accordingly.

```js
// vite.config.js
export default {
  base: '/production/',
};
```

You would then rebuild your app and copy / move the **contents** of the `dist` folder to the relevant location in your Apache document root. For example

```sh
cp -a dist/. /var/www/html/production/
```

---

Assuming you're using Vue Router with web history, you'll also need to configure the `base` parameter passed to `createWebHistory()`...

```js
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    /* ... */
  ],
})
```

Comment: I also followed this, no errors in the console whatsoever, I can see the icon on my browser tab. But the page is giving me white screen.

Comment: wow that actually works. My router was just this ```createWebHistory()``` adding the base parameter works. I'm kinda new to this, can you explain what happened?

Comment: Everything needs to work in concert. The router couldn't match your `/production` prefixed URLs to its routes so it was showing you a blank page. Once you told it that was the prefix for everything, it was able to match